# Under what conditions can TryDequeue and similar System.Collections.Concurrent collection methods fail

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have recently noticed that inside the collection objects contained in [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) namespace it is common to see `Collection.TrySomeAction()` rather then `Collection.SomeAction()`.

What is the cause of this? I assume it has something to do with locking?

So I am wondering under what conditions could an attempt to (for example) Dequeue an item from a stack, queue, bag etc.. fail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace are considered to be thread-safe, so it is possible to use them to write multi-threaded programs that share data between threads.

Before .NET 4, you had to provide your own synchronization mechanisms if multiple threads might be accessing a single shared collection. You had to lock the collection each time you modified its elements. You also might need to lock the collection each time you accessed (or enumerated) it. That’s for the simplest of multi-threaded scenarios. Some applications would create background threads that delivered results to a shared collection over time. Another thread would read and process those results. You needed to implement your own message passing scheme between threads to notify each other when new results were available, and when those new results had been consumed. The classes and interfaces in `System.Collections.Concurrent` provide a consistent implementation for those and other common multi-threaded programming problems involving shared data across threads in *lock-free* way.

*`Try<something>`* has semantics - *try* to do that action and return operation result. *`DoThat`* semantics usually use exception thrown mechanics to indicate error which can be not efficient. As examples there they can return false,

- if you *try* add new element, you might *already have it* in `ConcurentDictionary`;
- if you *try* to get element from collection, it might *not exists* there;
- if you *try* to update element there are can be more recent element already, so method ensures it updates only element which intended to update.

Try to read:

- [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en) - best to start;
- [Parallel Programming in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx);
- read [articles on Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/ee851578%28en-us%29.aspx)
- [Thread-safe Collections in .NET Framework 4 and Their Performance Characteristics](http://services.social.microsoft.com/feeds/FeedItem?feedId=639a99a9-ff25-4062-b61d-a86ea9d66a06&itemId=404a24fa-4820-4895-89ef-58d6e8f08d12&title=Thread-safe%20Collections%20in%20.NET%20Framework%204%20and%20Their%20Performance%20Characteristics&uri=http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/PerformanceCharacteristicsOfThreadSafeCollection.pdf&k=UlnHGXI3sO5fcC8zyrBezt9FtcGk8fmN6IYqNX2gQFc=)

Answer (score 11):

What do you mean with *fail*?

Take the following example:

```
var queue = new Queue<string>();
string temp = queue.Dequeue();
// do something with temp
```

The above code with throw an exception, since we try to dequeue from an empty queue. Now, if you use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead:

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
string temp;
if (queue.TryDequeue(out temp))
{
    // do something with temp
}
```

The above code will not throw an exception. The queue will still fail to dequeue an item, but the code will not fail in the way of throwing an exception. The real use for this becomes apparent in a multithreaded environment. Code for the non-concurrent `Queue<T>` would typically look something like this:

```
lock (queueLock)
{
    if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        string temp = queue.Dequeue();
        // do something with temp   
    } 
}
```

In order to avoid race conditions, we need to use a lock to ensure that nothing happens with the queue in the time that passes from checking `Count` do calling `Dequeue`. With `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, we don't really need to check `Count`, but can instead call `TryDequeue`.

If you examine the types found in the `Systems.Collections.Concurrent` namespace you will find that many of them wrap two operations that are typically called sequentially, and that would traditionally require locking (`Count` followed by `Dequeue` in `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, `GetOrAdd` in `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` replaces sequences of calling `ContainsKey`, adding an item and getting it, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to be "dequeued", for example... This "Try-Pattern" is used commonly all across FCL and BCL elements. That has nothing to do with locking, concurrent collections are (or at least should be) mostly implemented without locks...

Comment: I would say it has everything to do with locking. With the non-concurrent `Queue`, you need to use locking to avoid potential exceptions coming from one thread checking `Count` and getting `1` as result, a second thread then dequeuing the last item, followed by the first thread attempting to dequeue. `TryDequeue` solves this without the need for locking mechanisms in the calling code.

Comment: No, it has not, at least not as the client code is concerned. It is not even said that internally locking has to occur at all. As mentioned above, many operations can be implemented in thread-safe but lock-free manner... The behaviour of the TryXY methods in this context is exactly the same as with other elements using the "Try-Pattern", see (the non-concurrent) Dictionary.TryGetValue, for example.

Comment: I actually think we are saying the same thing, but from different angles. I am not saying that the concurrent collections contain locks (I am not quite aware of their internals). What I mean is that the `TryXY` methods provides means of doing things that would otherwise in many (but not all) cases require the *calling code* to contain locking mechanisms in order to prevent race conditions (`ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue` and `ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue` being very clear examples).